# Powershell script to keep computer awake remotely

Tags: powershell, sleep, power-management, sccm

My colleagues and I work in a global business environment that requires us to do software rollouts after staff leaves (to reduce productivity impact) and what is frequently happening is that due to our power settings that I have no power to change, machines are going to sleep about 15 minutes after they leave the office and I still need to access them. They don't receive or install the SCCM package I send because they are asleep. Wake on LAN is not an option because of the hardware variety we have

What would be the easiest way in Powershell to batch keep several machines (possibly 200+) awake? And not bring down our network while doing it? I'm looking to create a script and I would prefer not to have to push it to the machine but rather do it remotely.

UPDATE:
So far one of my co-worker's solution was to run a wait command in CMD remotely for a specified time inside but I don't know if that would keep it awake? What constitutes "activity" as far as power management is concerned?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to say it, but I'm not sure you can given how tightly your hands are bound and your druthers.

One semi-remote solution would be to push out a scheduled task to your client computers.  You can specify the `Wake the computer to run this task` option on the Conditions tab.  The Action could run a script silently from a network share, display a message, etc.  What it actually does isn't likely very important, though the script could be coded to do something you find useful in your org.

Set the other settings creatively and securely enough and off the top of my head I can't think of any glaring security issues.

Comment: I think this would be a pretty simple solution. I will see what I can do to implement it. Thanks EdgeVB

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 easy steps on how to create batch file app clicker to keep your windows 10 awake for as long as you want.

1 - Install Java JDK download link: https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html

2- copy paste the following code in a notepad and save it as CLICKER.JAVA in your drive like C:\CLICKER.JAVA

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class clicker {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    while(true){

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        robot.delay(60000);

        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    }}}
```

3- Open another notepad and copy past the following commands and save this file as batch file into your Desktop such as AWAKE.BAT

@echo off

mode con: cols=50 lines=10

@echo Started. Press CTRL+C few times to quit.

@echo off

set root=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin

cd %root%

java "c:\start.java"